# Change textbox BackColor in code-behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can i change textbox BackColor in code-behind to something like this:

```
Textbox1.BackColor = "#F2F0E1
```

instead of

```
Textbox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.White
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
Textbox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F2F0E1");
```

Answer (score 3):

Style sheet

```
.focusfld
{
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
}


   .normalfld
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Javascript

```
function DoFocus(fld) 
{
    fld.className = 'focusfld';
}
function DoBlur(fld) 
{
    fld.className='normalfld';
}
```

Code behind

```
   TempTextBox.Attributes.Add("onFocus", "DoFocus(this);");
    TempTextBox.Attributes.Add("onBlur", "DoBlur(this);");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to get Color from Hex string

---

```
    public Color HexColor(String hex)
    {
     //remove the # at the front
     hex = hex.Replace("#", "");

     byte a = 255;
     byte r = 255;
     byte g = 255;
     byte b = 255;

     int start = 0;

     //handle ARGB strings (8 characters long)
     if (hex.Length == 8)
     {
         a = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
         start = 2;
     }

     //convert RGB characters to bytes
     r = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
     g = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start+2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
     b = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start+4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

     return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
    }
```

then set

```
 Color c = HexColor("#F2F0E1");

Textbox1.BackColor =  HexColor("#F2F0E1");
```

OR

```
Textbox1.BackColor = c;
```

reference : http://silverlemma.blogspot.com/2009/03/c-converting-from-hex-string-to-color.html