# Adding bracket when key in a number

Tags: c#, asp.net, numbers, brackets

Let's say I have a textboxA. When the application runs, textboxA will be shown and user can enter a number. I wanted to format the user input to red color font and enclose with brackets.

Example: If user enter '5', I will format the input to (5), with red color.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: you want achieve that in client side or server side??

Comment: I wanted to achieve it at the client side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3870087/706456, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6153068/706456

Answer (score 0):

```
function format(input) {

        var txtValue = document.getElementById(input).value;
        document.getElementById(input).value = "("+txtValue+ ")";
document.getElementById(input).style="color:red;";


    }
```

Use above javascript function and call in your textbox like this `onchange="format(this);"`

Comment: I've tried something like this but it doesn't work. Here's the code:
    private code txtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    String txt = txtBox.Text;
    txtBox.Text = "(" + txt + ")";
    txtBox.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF0000");

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me-

Your textbox would be-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onchange="javascript:formatText(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

On client side write a function as follows-

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function formatText(input) {
        var txtValue = document.getElementById(input.id).value;
        document.getElementById(input.id).style = "color:Red;";
        document.getElementById(input.id).value = "(" + txtValue + ")";        
    }
</script>
```